# CSS list resizing issue

Tags: css

i'm trying to make a header with a horizontal list. On my laptop screen it works as i want, but when i resize my browser, the list itens get out of the header div. Can someone help me please?

Image 1 - full size window:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nigad.png)

Image 2 - when i resize:
[red arrow points were i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80fEQ.png)

My code: 
**HTML**

```
   <div class="divcabecalho">
   <img src="Imagens/Symbol_of_Incheon.svg.png">
          <ul class="listacabecalho">

       <li>aaaaa</li>
       <li>aaaaa</li>
       <li>aaaaa</li>
                  <li>aaaaa</li>
       <li>aaaaa</li>
       <li>aaaaa</li>
                  <li>aaaaa</li>
       <li>aaaaa</li>
       <li>aaaaa</li>
   </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
html {
min-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
min-height: 100vh;
height: 100vh;
max-height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
padding:0px;
background: #fafafa;
font-family: Trebuchet MS;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.divcabecalho {
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: dodgerblue;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.listacabecalho {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;

}

.listacabecalho li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100px;
}

.listacabecalho img {
    width: auto;

    height: 100px;
}

.principalcabecalho {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    margin: 0;

}

img {
    display: inline;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: correct list structure is: **<ul><li></li></ul>**

Comment: They don't have enough room to fit in the row. Where do you suggest they go when they run our of room?

Comment: The minimal pre-requisite of building web pages is learning what each of the most used tags do and going over a few examples to get familiar with the basics. Until you do that, you cannot consider yourself a programmer and this community will, most likely, not welcome your questions. [so] is clearly oriented towards and dedicated to programmers. Please, show some effort in trying to become one.

Comment: thanks @techLove, but that doesn't solve my issue :c

Comment: @Tom i wanted it to create the row like it does but on the blue area, not outside of it, don't know if its possible

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu im trying to learn ok? i don't consider myself as a programmer, only as a guy who's trying to learn something..

Comment: @TgeiEsrp, I congratulate you on your decision. In order to be welcome here, you need to respect the rules of the community. And the first rule is you have to be a programmer. Because we don't want clients, who don't know anything and don't care about learning to just come and ask for free work. In order to set yourself apart from them, you need to show some basic learning effort. Asking a question about a `<li>` containing `<ul>`s, not the other way around, tells us you haven't made that effort. Not sure if you realize it, but I'm trying to be nice and helpful.

Answer (score 0):

See if this gets you unstuck: https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/ybvqpw

I removed the height declarations on the ul and li selectors

Good luck!

```
.listacabecalho {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* min-width: 100%; */
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  /* height: 100px; */
  /* line-height: 100px; */
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.listacabecalho li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin: 0;
/*     height: 100px; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the line-height you've set on the list items is causing it to stack improperly.  By removing the line height and adding some padding to the list items, you can achieve the look you'd like.

```
.listacabecalho {
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    color: white;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 2em 0;
}
```

Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwvdfbmh/1/) .